# Runtime Error while Saving a PyTorch Model: "File /path/to/be/saved Cannot Be Opened"

Tags: python, pytorch

I run a CNN model on CIFAR-10 using PyTorch and use [the official PyTorch tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/saving_and_loading_a_general_checkpoint.html#:%7E:text=4.-,Save%20the%20general%20checkpoint,-Collect%20all%20relevant) to save a general checkpoint.

When the training and testing is completed I pass the last epoch to this `save_model` function.

```
def save_model(epoch):
    torch.save({
        'epoch': epoch+1,
        'model_state_dict': net.state_dict(),
        'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict(),
        }, '/home/cc/research/AdderNet/pretrained/minionn.pt')
```

However, I keep getting the following error while trying to save the model:

```
> Train - Epoch 1, Batch: 1, Loss: 2.302385
> Test Avg. Loss: 0.020081, Accuracy: 0.269100
> Train - Epoch 2, Batch: 1, Loss: 2.019350
> Test Avg. Loss: 0.018918, Accuracy: 0.324800
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/cc/research/AdderNet/main.py", line 119, in <module>
> main()
> File "/home/cc/research/AdderNet/main.py", line 115, in main
> save_model(epoch)
> File "/home/cc/research/AdderNet/main.py", line 105, in save_model
> torch.save({
> File "/home/cc/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 422, in save
> with _open_zipfile_writer(f) as opened_zipfile:
> File "/home/cc/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 309, in _open_zipfile_writer
> return container(name_or_buffer)
> File "/home/cc/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 287, in __init__
> super(_open_zipfile_writer_file, self).__init__(torch._C.PyTorchFileWriter(str(name)))
> **RuntimeError: File /home/cc/research/AdderNet/pretrained/minionn.pt cannot be opened.**
```

What do you think is the problem? Please, let me know if any other details need to be added. I am running my code on a remote server using VsCode. I am also using a virtual environment that I created with conda. The python version installed in the venv is `Python 3.10.8` but the conda's base python version is `Python 3.9.13` and my system's default python version (when I deactivate conda) is `Python 3.8.10`. The operating system is also `Ubuntu20.04`.

**Updated:**

I am able to save the model using the following:

```
torch.save(model, '/home/cc/research/AdderNet/pretrained/FILE_NAME')
```

But since I want to load and continue training the saved model, PyTorch instructs to use this approach which apparently doesn't work for me:

```
torch.save({
            'epoch': EPOCH,
            'model_state_dict': net.state_dict(),
            'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict(),
            'loss': LOSS,
            }, '/home/cc/research/AdderNet/pretrained/FILE_NAME.pt')
```

Comment: Does the directory `/home/cc/research/AdderNet/pretrained` exist?

Comment: The path is valid. What do you mean if it exists? I don't have any files called `minionn.pt` though. Shouldn't it create it itself or something?

Comment: I don't know about this software specifically, but in general, it is expected that the directory itself does already exist.  So I will repeat my question: Does that directory already exist?

Comment: Yes yes, the directory exists.

Comment: Is that directory writable by whatever user is executing the program?

Comment: I was able to save the whole model using this code: `torch.save(model, /home/cc/research/AdderNet/pretrained/file-name)`. So I assume the answer is yes.

Comment: So if you were able to do that, then that file does already exist, right?  But you also said that the file _doesn't_ exist in an earlier comment.  So I am confused.

Comment: I edited my last comment. Last time, I used a different file name without any extension `.pt`. I'm not really familiar with this either but I think one only saves the whole model while the other also keeps track of parameters such as `number_of_epochs` which comes handy for reloading and continue training . I've been following the PyTorch tutorial.

Comment: If the directory exists and is writable by you, and the specific filename does not exist, then I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem on windows machine. I was trying to save the model with timestamp

```
model_path = os.path.join(model_dir, str(datetime.datetime.now())+".pth")
torch.save(self.state_dict(), model_path)
```

It was throwing the same error once I removed the timestamp it worked for me

```
model_path = os.path.join(model_dir, "model"+".pth")
torch.save(self.state_dict(), model_path)
```

do not know the reason but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

oh yeah, I had some code that tried to `torch.save` a model in a list with other important model info and that failed, so I used `torch.jit.save` which worked but that's not the point.

If you want to save the other important model stuff then I think it's best to just keep the model in one file and the other important things in another file. That works, and well, another file couldn't hurt anyone.

Comment: This doesn't address the question of why the error happened.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34430397)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your file name contains invalid characters, anyway, I solved it by this way (for example, Windows file names cannot contain /:, etc.).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I too was facing the same error when trying to save my torch model. In
[this tutorial that you have linked](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/saving_and_loading_a_general_checkpoint.html#:%7E:text=4.-,Save%20the%20general%20checkpoint,-Collect%20all%20relevant), the version of `torch` used is `1.13.1+cu116`. Try using this same version and I believe it should resolve your error.